# after submitting form in php, success message modal not loading

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have form which is in a modal, when the user clicks the button the modal opens and he fills the details, and after submission the details go to my mail, till here everything is fine. After the submit button, the page again loads, so i have created a modal for thanks message like below:

```html
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $to = "contact@solutions.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['name1']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['name2'];
    $last_name = $_POST['email2'];
    $last_name1 = $_POST['number1'];
    $subject = "Referal";
    $subject2 = "Bolster Referal.";
    $message = $from . " has refered the following student :" . "\n\n" . $first_name. "\n\n" .$last_name. "\n\n" .$last_name1;
    $message2 = "Your friend " . $from . " has refered you to us" ;

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($last_name,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    //echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
    // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
    echo "<script>
         $(window).load(function(){
             $('#thankyouModal').modal('show');
         });
    </script>";
    }
?>
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="thankyouModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Thank you for pre-registering!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Thanks for getting in touch!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but after the user submits the details, the thanks message popup is not loading, can anyone please tell me what coul be wrong in my doing. thanks in advance

Comment: What happens instead? Is the expected JS code written to the markup? Does it trigger any error message?

Comment: echo "<script>
         $(window).load(function(){
             $('#thankyouModal').modal('show');
         });
    </script>"; this is only the js code for the thanks message

Comment: @NicoHaase the form is being submitted and the page just reloads after the submission

Comment: That does not answer my question - is that markup written properly?

Comment: @NicoHaase i didnt get you, which code are you talking about, the whole code or only the thanks message

Comment: If the modal is not triggered, I'd assume that the code to load that modal is not present in your markup

Comment: @NicoHaase i am new to this, i think i didn't mention the code which selects the html code in the modal, something like  document.getelementbyid

Comment: Can you please tell me how do i connect my html to javascript

Answer (score 0):

`$(window).load(function ());` does not work in latest versions of jQuery.

So just replace the following code.

```
   $(window).on("load", function () {
        $('#thankyouModal').modal('show');
    });
```